# Sorting a txt file with python alphabetically?

Tags: python, sorting, alphabetical

## Top of my code

```
player_name = input('Please enter your first and last name: ')

player_class = input('Please enter your class. {Class 1, Class 2 or Class 3}: ')

player_class = "N:\General homework\Computer Science\Class Files\\" + 
player_class + '.txt'
```

## Bottom of my code

```
average_score = (int(score_1) + int(score_2) + int(score_3)) / 3

write_to_file = player_name + ' ' + str(score_1) + "/10" + ' ' + str(score_2) + "/10" + ' ' + str(score_3) + "/10" + ' Average is ' + str(round(average_score))
 + "/10" + "\n"

file = open(player_class,"a")

file.write(write_to_file)

file.close()
```

I've been searching for a while, and I have no idea how to alphabetically sort this. If i were to input the name as Ben and class as Class 1, then as Alice and Class 1, it would still show Ben first. Ive tried the  sorted{} function and it just doesnt work. I need this for an assessment and have no idea what to do! Please help if you can :(

Comment: You are overwriting the value of the `player_class` variable with the file path. Also, you only seem to write a single line of text to your file. What's there to sort? Can you give the expected output?

Comment: I am trying to make it so each time it I run the code and it adds a new line to the text file, It will also sort the whole file at the same time. This means when there are multiple lines it should sort them. If i were to say one person was called Ben and another Alice, it would come out as


Ben, 0/10 0/10 0/10 (Its a maths quiz those are the scores)
Alice, 0/10 0/10 0/10

Then, I want it to sort the file so Alice goes first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the players in memory in some kind of data structure, e.g. a [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Once you have a list containing the things you want to sort, then you can use `sorted()` to alphabetize it, and then use the sorted list to write all of the players to a file in order.

Comment: ok, I think I can do that. Thanks! That makes a lot more sense than what im trying to do!